# VirtualBox 6.0.14: shared folder doesn't appear in "/media"

Tags: virtualbox

In VirtualBox 6.0.14 with an Ubuntu Linux guest (Guest Additions installed ...), this shared folder does not show up in `/media` as advertised.  (The only thing that's there is `/media/cdrom`.)

Why doesn't my share show up?

[image: VirtualBox share definition screen]

Answer (score 4):

Well, I answered my own question with a little searching here in StackExchange:  the virtualbox guest additions *kernel modules* were not installed.  And the VB documentation really didn't point that out.  So, here's what solved the problem:

- On the *Devices* menu of the running virtual machine, click "*Insert Guest Additions CD Image."*
- If necessary, `sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom` to make a mount-point.  *(You can of course use any directory as a mount-point ...)*
- `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom` to mount the CD there.
- `cd /mnt/cdrom` to go inside.
- `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
- ... wait for it to do its thing ... it will compile and install the modules, but they won't be loaded yet.
- `sudo reboot`

Now, `mount | grep vboxsf` will show that there now is a mounted filesystem. *(This is because I specified "auto-mount" as you see in the original post.  If you don't do that, you'll have to fiddle with `/etc/fstab`, which I won't go into here ...)*

You might find, however, that you get `Permission Denied` when you try to look inside!  Now's a good time to remember that you must be a member of the `vboxsf` group.  (`ls -l /mnt/*` will show the group-name and permissions mask.)  Here's what to do:

`sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf yourusername` *(Note: with a **capital** `-G`!)*  Then, log off and log back on again so that the changes take effect.  Confirm this with the `groups` command, which will now list this group as one that you belong to.  *(Of course, you can use fuzzy GUI tools to manage the user's group memberships if you prefer.)*